# Use JQuery to get data from select multiple tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I would like to use select multiple tab in html like

```
<select name="foo" multiple>
    <option value="all">option1</option>
    <option value="all">option2</option>    
    <option value="all">option3</option>                        
</select>
```

How can I get data in javascript from this multiple select tab

I tried

```
var  foo  =  [];
$('#foo:selected').each(
function(i,selected) {
    foo[i] = $(selected).text();
}
);
```

But no luck, it doesn't work. It shows foo.length==0

What is the correct way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#foo:selected')
```

should be

```
$('#foo option:selected')
```

Selected attribute is a `property of the options inside select` and not `select element.`

Secondly you have no element with `id="foo"`

```
$('[name=foo] option:selected') // for this case
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#foo:selected')
```

This tries to find instances of `#foo` which are selected.  But that's the `select` element itself, not the options therein.  Try with the options:

```
$('#foo option:selected')
```

**Update:** It looks like the first part of the selector is wrong, too.  You don't actually have an element of id `foo` so `#foo` won't find anything.  What you have is a `select` element with the *name* `foo`.  So something like this instead:

```
$('select[name="foo"] option:selected')
```

Comment: I tried what you said here, it still doesn't work, foo.length shows 0

Comment: @AlfredZhong: You're right, I hadn't noticed that `#foo` itself is also wrong, since you don't have an element with that id.  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var foo = [];

$("[name='foo']").change(function () {
  $("[name='foo'] option:selected").each(function (i, selected) {
      foo[i] = $(this).text();
  });
})
.trigger('change');
```